# How do you make the CreateFileA WINAPI function work in this form?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this WINAPI function:

```
HANDLE file{ CreateFileA((LPCSTR)"\\\\.\\" + (???) ", FILE_APPEND_DATA,FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL) };
```

I have a global variable "Path" of type std::string & a username which is type TCHAR*, I assume I need to convert those two variables to LPCSTR, however, I have no idea how to do that even after some time of googling. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you want to use the A version? You surely should be using the Unicode version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply concatenate the two `std::string`s into a new `std::string`, and then use its `c_str()` method, eg:

```cpp
std::string Path = ...;
std::string username = ...;
std::string fullpath = Path + username;

HANDLE file{ CreateFileA(fullpath.c_str(), ...) };
```

Or simply:

```cpp
std::string Path = ...;
std::string username = ...;

HANDLE file{ CreateFileA((Path + username).c_str(), ...) };
```